# Equivalent to `onEndReached` for React

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement an infinite list for a React project and I'd like to know if there is an equivalent to the `onEndReached` from `react-native` that I could use to get this done easily. The idea would be to have an `offset` and a `limit` in my request so that I can append a batch of elements after I reached the end of my list.

I haven't found many options except some already complete components but I do need to implement mine.

I also found this question from January 27 ([How can I implement a robust onEndReached for ScrollView on React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903023/how-can-i-implement-a-robust-onendreached-for-scrollview-on-react-native)) but since he doesn't have any answer I thought I should ask here.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By quick Googling, this can detect when you scroll to an element. It can call your callback to fetch more items.

https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint

Comment: I'm gonna try this ! I'll keep you informed :)